# How can I use <style> tags in TEXY AJAX editor?

Tags: html, css, ajax

I am using this [TEXY AJAX editor](https://editor.texy.info/) for my creations, however it seems like it is not supporting `<style>` tags. Try put this piece of code there and see yourself:

```css
.mine {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  color: blue; 
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mine">Hello</div>
<div>There!</div>
```

It completely ignores `<style>`s and `<script>`s. Here is a syntax guide https://texy.info/en/syntax. I don´t even know what AJAX means, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
.{border: 1px solid black; color: blue; width: 100px;}
Hello
```

**Article about taxy syntax:** https://texy.info/en/syntax

Comment: And what if I want to use media queries or something more complicated like scripts for small apps?

Comment: I did, still not working, You can try it yourself, it just completely ignores it.

Comment: Ok try this:
.{color:blue}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
you just type .{} and then content

Answer (score 0):

Try with writing CSS in a separate file and import that CSS file.